# How can I remove the red exclaimation mark from the adf mobile app?

Tags: ios, ipad, jdeveloper, oracle-adf-mobile

I have created an iOS app in ADF mobile framework of Oracle.

I see the red exclamation mark on top of every page that runs on 7.1 SDK.
Simulator is iPad based.
I have removed all the warnings which were highlighted in the jdeveloper for the shortDesc attribute.

How can I remove that red exclamation mark?

attaching screenshot for more clarity.
[image: image showing red exclamation mark]

Comment: Can you see your code and let me know if there is any warning?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the code and there were warnings for the shortDesc attributes. I added those and still getting the red exclamation.

Comment: Guess they didn't expect anyone to clear all warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That little red exclamation point means **you've deployed the app in debug mode**. ADF mobile allows you to compile in both a debug and a release mode, one is for testing and the other is when you want to publish a completed product.

I generally deploy all the time in release mode because the performance is much better and the exclamation point annoys me too! To change this go to Application->Deploy->New Deployment Profile and after populating those settings, click on "iOS Options" and toggle the build mode there from "Debug" to "Release".

Doing this will also eliminate the "This ADF Mobile app was deployed in Debug mode and should not be used for performance evaluation purposes" warning you may see in the Deployment log.